# Iterating over date ranges in pandas dataframe with for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm trying to iterate over the timestamp in each row of a dataframe to see whether that timestamp is before or after a specific date. In addition, I want to create a new column in the dataframe that specifies whether the date is before or after the specified date.

This is the code I'm using:

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], errors='coerce')

for row in df.iterrows():
        if df[(df['created_at'] >= '2019-03-15')]:
            df['within_date_range'] = "True"
        else:
            df['within_date_range'] = "False"
```

However, the above code gives me this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any clarifications would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why loop? `df['within_date_range'] = df.created_at.ge('2019-03-15')`

Comment: As ~@ALollz commented, you don't need to loop to do this. But if you do want to loop, notice that within the loop you're not using the `row`, but querying the whole dataframe on each iteration. Basically, in the `if` clause you're passing the dataframe filtered for the rows in which `created_at` is larger than `2019-03-15`. Obviously, a dataframe is not True or False, and that's why you get that `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous`

Comment: Thanks @ALollz. That did the trick. I wasn't aware of Pandas greater than-equal function. Very neat: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you also can use np.where function to get the condition

```
df['within_date_range'] = np.where(df['created_at'] >= '2019-03-15', 'True', 'False')
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, you really don't need the loop for this.
But answering your exact question, the source of your error is this expression:
`if df[(df['created_at'] >= '2019-03-15')]:`.

In fact, the operation `df[some_condition_here]` returns you a new `DataFrame`, and it is not clear how to cast `DataFrame` to `boolean` value *(and it is also working for any class: is `dog = new Dog()` instance true or false?)*

This is why you're getting your error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. This makes sense. @ALollz suggested an answer above but I'd be interested in knowing what form the for loop SHOULD have taken to work correctly on a row-by-row basis?